# Jenkins Password Param in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to add a `passwordParam` to my Jenkins groovy file as such.
The intention is to have the password picked up by a job at runtime

```
pipelineJob(jobName) {
    displayName(displayString)
    parameters {
        choiceParam('ARTEFACT',artefactName,'Artefact to deploy?')
        choiceParam('CLUSTER',cluster,'Cluster to push to')
        stringParam('BRANCH','main','What branch should be used?')
        passwordParam('proxyUser', 'password123', 'ProxyPassword')
    }
```

But I get the error

```
ERROR: (job_delete_release.groovy, line 23) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.passwordParam() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [proxyUser, password123, ProxyPassword]
```

According to the documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-parameters) it should be possible.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing DSL and Declarative syntaxs.

What you are writing here is JobDSL, however your link is to declarative code.
In the section you are writing you can only use the parameters available to JobDSL which can be found here:

Click the three dots in the parameters on  https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.MavenJob.parameters

So for the JobDSL I believe you would use `nonStoredPasswordParam` (note I have never used it)

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.MavenJob.parameters-nonStoredPasswordParam

If you wanted your parameters in Declarative you would write them inside the `pipeline` section.
e.g.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'script_args', defaultValue: '--out_file --purge', description: 'Command line args to pass to script')
  }
```